How to solve truth tables in Wolfram Alpha?
How can I build a truth table out of this formula in Wolfram Alpha:
((A and(if B then C)) or (C and not A))


((A and(B Implies C)) or (C and not A))

or
((A and(C and not B)) or (C and not A))

